# HTML/Javascript website stops working from time to time - how to debug it?

Tags: javascript

I have a website with a graph and a data table. The whole works on a tiny PCB with a microcontroller ESP8266, so this page is loaded to it as a char table in C language. Unfortunately for some reason, once every few hours the page hangs. The page code is below. Unfortunately I have no experience in javascript and debugging problems with web pages. Is there any way to identify the problem with the browser tools (F12)? Unless one of you is able to spot immediately what the problem may be?
The whole thing is based on https://circuits4you.com/2019/01/11/esp8266-data-logging-with-real-time-graphs/.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Monitor Warunków Środowiskowych - Serwerownia</title>
    
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@0.7.7"></script>  
    <style>
    canvas{
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
    }

    /* Data Table Styling */
    #dataTable {
      font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #dataTable td, #dataTable th {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: 8px;
    }

    #dataTable tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

    #dataTable tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

    #dataTable th {
      padding-top: 12px;
      padding-bottom: 12px;
      text-align: left;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }
    </style>

<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;margin:0px auto;}
.tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-7vwr{background-color:#fd6864;border-color:#c0c0c0;color:#ffffff;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-wtex{border-color:#c0c0c0;font-weight:bold;text-align:right;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-bx42{border-color:#c0c0c0;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="chart-container" position: relative; height:350px; width:100%">
        <canvas id="Chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
<br>
<br>

<div>
<table class="tg" id="minmaxtemp">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-7vwr">Temperatura - zarejestrowane wartości graniczne</th>
    <th class="tg-7vwr">Minimalna</th>
    <th class="tg-7vwr">Maksymalna</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-wtex">Wartość [&deg;C]</td>
    <td class="tg-bx42"></td>
    <td class="tg-bx42"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-wtex">Czas</td>
    <td class="tg-bx42"></td>
    <td class="tg-bx42"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div>
    <table id="dataTable">
      <tr><th>Czas</th><th>Temperatura [&deg;C]</th><th>Wilgotność [%]</th></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<br>
<br>    

<script>

var valuesT = [];
var valuesH = [];
var timeStamp = [];

var TempValue;
var HumValue;
var PressValue;

var minmaxstring;

var TempValueMin = 200.0;
var TempValueMax = -200.0;

function showGraph()
{
    //for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    //  valuesT.push(arguments[i]);    
    //}

    var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart").getContext('2d');
    var Chart2 = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: timeStamp,  //Bottom Labeling
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Temperatura",
                    fill: false,    //Try with true
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba( 255, 51, 51 , 1)', //Dot marker color
                    borderColor: 'rgba( 255, 51, 51 , 1)',  //Graph Line Color
                    data: valuesT,
                },
                {
                    label: "Wilgotność",
                    fill: false,    //Try with true
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba( 3, 194, 252 , 1)', //Dot marker color
                    borderColor: 'rgba( 3, 194, 252 , 1)',  //Graph Line Color
                    data: valuesH,
                }
            
            ],
        },
        
        options: {
            title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: "Monitor Warunków Środowiskowych - Serwerownia"
                },
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            elements: {
            line: {
                    tension: 0 //Smoothening (Curved) of data lines
                }
            },
            scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }]
            },
            animation: {
                duration: 0
            },
            plugins: {
    zoom: {
        // Container for pan options
        pan: {
            // Boolean to enable panning
            enabled: true,

            // Panning directions. Remove the appropriate direction to disable
            // Eg. 'y' would only allow panning in the y direction
            // A function that is called as the user is panning and returns the
            // available directions can also be used:
            //   mode: function({ chart }) {
            //     return 'xy';
            //   },
            mode: 'xy',

            rangeMin: {
                // Format of min pan range depends on scale type
                x: null,
                y: null
            },
            rangeMax: {
                // Format of max pan range depends on scale type
                x: null,
                y: null
            },

            // On category scale, factor of pan velocity
            speed: 20,

            // Minimal pan distance required before actually applying pan
            threshold: 10,

            // Function called while the user is panning
            onPan: function({chart}) { console.log(`I'm panning!!!`); },
            // Function called once panning is completed
            onPanComplete: function({chart}) { console.log(`I was panned!!!`); }
        },

        // Container for zoom options
        zoom: {
            // Boolean to enable zooming
            enabled: true,

            // Enable drag-to-zoom behavior
            drag: true,

            // Drag-to-zoom effect can be customized
            // drag: {
            //   borderColor: 'rgba(225,225,225,0.3)'
            //   borderWidth: 5,
            //   backgroundColor: 'rgb(225,225,225)',
            //   animationDuration: 0
            // },

            // Zooming directions. Remove the appropriate direction to disable
            // Eg. 'y' would only allow zooming in the y direction
            // A function that is called as the user is zooming and returns the
            // available directions can also be used:
            //   mode: function({ chart }) {
            //     return 'xy';
            //   },
            mode: 'xy',

            rangeMin: {
                // Format of min zoom range depends on scale type
                x: null,
                y: null
            },
            rangeMax: {
                // Format of max zoom range depends on scale type
                x: null,
                y: null
            },

            // Speed of zoom via mouse wheel
            // (percentage of zoom on a wheel event)
            speed: 0.1,

            // Minimal zoom distance required before actually applying zoom
            threshold: 2,

            // On category scale, minimal zoom level before actually applying zoom
            sensitivity: 3,

            // Function called while the user is zooming
            onZoom: function({chart}) { console.log(`I'm zooming!!!`); },
            // Function called once zooming is completed
            onZoomComplete: function({chart}) { console.log(`I was zoomed!!!`); }
        }
    }
}
        }
    });

}


//On Page load show graphs
window.onload = function() {
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    //showGraph(0,0,0,0);
};

//Ajax script to get Temperature at every Second
//Read This tutorial https://circuits4you.com/2018/02/04/esp8266-ajax-update-part-of-web-page-without-refreshing/

setInterval(function() {
  // Call a function repetatively with Second interval
  getDataTemperature();
  getDataHumidity();
  getMinMax();
  updateTable();
}, 5000); //update rate [ms]
 
function getDataTemperature() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        TempValue = this.responseText; 

    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "readBME280_temperature", true);    //Handle readBME280 server on ESP8266
  xhttp.send();


}

function getDataHumidity() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        
        HumValue = this.responseText;

    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "readBME280_humidity", true);   //Handle readBME280 server on ESP8266
  xhttp.send();
}

function getDataPressure() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        
        PressValue = this.responseText;

    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "readBME280_pressure", true);   //Handle readBME280 server on ESP8266
  xhttp.send();
}

function getMinMax() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        
        minmaxstring = this.responseText;

    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "readMinMax", true);
  xhttp.send();
}


function updateTable() {
    
      var timeutc = new Date();
      timeutc.setHours( timeutc.getHours() + 2 );
      var time = timeutc.toLocaleTimeString();
    
      //values.push(TemperatureValue);
      if (TempValue != null && HumValue != null){
            valuesT.push(TempValue);
            valuesH.push(HumValue);
            timeStamp.push(time);
            showGraph();    //Update Graphs

            //Update Data Table
            var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
            var row = table.insertRow(1);   //Add after headings
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            cell1.innerHTML = time;
            cell2.innerHTML = TempValue;
            cell3.innerHTML = HumValue;


        }

            var min_temp_cell = document.getElementById("minmaxtemp").rows[1].cells[1];
            min_temp_cell.innerHTML = minmaxstring.slice(0,5);
                
            var min_temp_time_cell = document.getElementById("minmaxtemp").rows[2].cells[1];
            min_temp_time_cell.innerHTML = minmaxstring.slice(5,24);


            var max_temp_cell = document.getElementById("minmaxtemp").rows[1].cells[2];
            max_temp_cell.innerHTML = minmaxstring.slice(24,29);
                
            var max_temp_time_cell = document.getElementById("minmaxtemp").rows[2].cells[2];
            max_temp_time_cell.innerHTML = minmaxstring.slice(29,48);

}
    
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to identify the problem with the browser tools (F12)?

It can't stop by itself.

There are 2 possible things you should take a look:

1. Errors in console. In DevTools (F12) go to "Console" tab. Look for a red text.
2. Network problems. In DevTools go to Network tab an search for "Status" = "Pending" (so it hangs) - **warning:** open DevTools before you run your site, otherwise Network panel will be empty

If you have one of this problems - just add description to the answer. Without the real problem here is nothing to fix.

**One last note**: the link, that you used as the origin of your code is structured in some different way. Take a look:

```js
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    /* ... */
    showGraph();
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

This is async request to the server. `onreadystatechange` is triggered as a result of that request. And only **after** that we call `showGraph()`.

But in your code I see:

```js
...
getDataTemperature();
getDataHumidity();
getMinMax();
updateTable();
...
```

So you are sending 3 requests and call to `updateTable` without waiting for a real response with a data.

Of course, it will not break your code, so this is not your problem, this is just a note of wrong structure.